# grub как восстановить переход в меню по стрелкам курсора?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, grub, boot

На жёстком диске установлен Linux Mint 18.3 (Grub 2)
Недавно обнаружил, что не могу осуществлять навигацию в меню стрелками курсора, + таймер 30 секунд, на Enter - тоже нулевая реакция (словно в этот момент клавиатура заблокирована).
Как-то можно вернуть grub2 в полностью рабочее состояние?

Comment: Система работает стабильно. Но факт, что этап загрузки и выбор загружаемого ядра безконтрольный - не даёт покоя...

Comment: Ну а самый простой вариант: *update-grub* пытались сделать ?

Answer (score 4):

Загрузчик GRUB2 умеет работать не только с графическими терминалами, но и с консолью (COM-порт). Возможно он ожидает ввода пользователя не с терминала а с настроенного COM-порта.

Проверьте содержимое файла **/etc/default/grub**

Для наглядности ниже приводится примерное содержимое этого файла:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=1
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

В случае, если ваш GRUB2 был настроен на COM порт, то вы увидите там что-то такое среди параметров:

```
GRUB_TERMINAL="serial console"
GRUB_SERIAL_COMMAND="serial --speed=115200"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=ttyS0,115200n8"
```

После внесения изменений в этот файл необходимо перегенерировать конфигурацию:

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Comment: У меня в файле **grub** следующее:                ```GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""``` @sasha-golikov Явно COM-port не задействован.

Comment: Закомментируйте  в /etc/default/grub строку GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0 (поставьте символ # перед ней), затем обновите конфигурацию grub при помощи grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg  . Альтернатива - нажать и держать кнопку Shift на клавиатуре во время загрузки компьютера. Тогда должно отобразиться меню при загрузке. Для редактирования текущих параметров загрузки в меню Grub нужно нажать кнопку 'e'.

Answer (score 0):

Ещё как один из вариантов, с которым я столкнулся - связан с оборудованием, а именно с клавиатурой.

В Биосе нужно проверить: подключена ли поддержка:

`- [x] USB-Keyboard support <ENABLED>`

У меня эта опция была выключена.